# ng model - check the checkbox Xpath not working in chrome and IE driver

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Html code:

```
<table id="tblusref" style="width: auto;" onmouseover="UsortBinders()" role="grid">
<thead>
<tbody aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
<tr class="ng-scope AssociateHighlight odd" >
<td class="ng-binding" style="width: 10px">1</td>
<td class=" text-center" style="width: 2px">
<input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" type="checkbox" ng-change="CheckChange(Ref.RecordNo,Ref.Freeze,Ref.isSelected,'US')" ng-model="Ref.isSelected">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

inside the table each and every row have an checkbox and i want to check the checkbox with particular row,and below is my xpath

```
WebElement checkBoxSelection = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tblusref']/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input"));
        checkBoxSelection.click();
```

Please clarify

but during the execution

Firefox - its working correctly but Chrome and IE not checked

Firefox driver: 2.51.0

Chrome driver: 2.53.1

IE driver: 2.42.2

Comment: Do you have an exception?

Comment: @Guy: i'm not getting any exception

Answer (score 0):

**Given element is not valid and also not able to find in console as well.**

Please **change element as per under of checkbox** (Use **one by one** and keep **whichever is proffered and working** for you):

1. `WebElement checkBoxSelection = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid']"));`
2. `WebElement checkBoxSelection = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class,'ng-valid')]"));`
   Here change internal class text as you get unique element.
3. `WebElement checkBoxSelection = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[class='ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid']"));`

**Then click on it.**

```
checkBoxSelection.click();
```

**As discuss in comment** , There is one more scenario I want to add. There may be list of web elements at same level of xpath. Please use index for it.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@class='ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid'])[1]"));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@class='ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid'])[2]"));
```

And so on...

**For particular this table the solution is :**

xpath : `(//table[@id='tblusref']//input[@class='ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid'])[1]`

Please let me know If any query.

Comment: Thanks , but inside the table there are n number of check boxes, so i that i want to traverse each row wise and check particular row.

Comment: Please let me know can you say you want to select this option ? with order? Answer is updated please check

Comment: traverse entire table and check only the particular checkbox, w.r.t. table row :(By.xpath("//*[@id='tblusref']/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]....

Comment: You can try this xpath //table[@id='tblusref'](//input[@class='ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid'])[1]

Comment: Please let me know it is working or not so i can update answer as well

Comment: getting unable to locate an element exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130468/discussion-between-sagar007-and-prabu).

Comment: My mistake try this (//table[@id='tblusref']//input[@class='ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid'])[1]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130501/discussion-between-prabu-and-sagar007).