# WebElement.Click() not working in Chrome and IE driver

Tags: google-chrome, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

Action:

i want to check the checkbox with the following xpath

```
WebElement checkBoxSelection = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tblusref']/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input"));
checkBoxSelection.click();
```

my xpath was correct, also verified with chrome developer tool, but during the execution its not click the checkbox, and i am not getting any exception

same its perfectly working in Firefox driver, its not working in Chrome and IE,
Please help how can i resolved this issue

driver dependency

```
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.1</version>

<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.42.2</version>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng model - check the checkbox Xpath not working in chrome and IE driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115126/ng-model-check-the-checkbox-xpath-not-working-in-chrome-and-ie-driver)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice.

Comment: @Guy: not duplicate, i have edited my previous question, and not getting feedback so that i raised new question with current issue

Answer (score 0):

```
try to update to version 3.X
update the chrome driver also 
i am adding a method that can help u debug 
it highlight the place you click 
(please use shorter path and if u can change it to css selector)

 public void highligh(By cssSelector) {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.border='2px groove green'", driver.findElement(cssSelector));
    }
```